# Kick off separate redux-saga on login and logout

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga, chatkit

I'm learning Redux-Saga and having a bit of trouble wrapping my head round the correct flow for connectng people to a chat service (Chatkit by Pusher) when they log in and disconnecting them on logout.

So far I have an "auth" saga which waits for a LOGIN_REQUEST action, logs in to a REST api using axios then stores a username and token in the store by calling a USER_SET action.

My question is, when the login happens and the credentials are stored, should I PUT a new action called something like CHAT_CONNECT which would kick off another saga to connect to Chatkit, or should I get the chat saga to listen to the LOGIN_SUCCESS being fired and act on that? Is there even any practical difference in these two approaches.

As a bonus question, what's the best way to receive and act on new websocket messages from Chatkit using Redux Sagas? Here's the boilerplate code for connecting and receiving events from chatkit.

```
chatManager
  .connect()
    .then(currentUser => {
      currentUser.subscribeToRoom({
        roomId: currentUser.rooms[0].id,
        hooks: {
          onNewMessage: message => {
            console.log(`Received new message: ${message.text}`)
          }
        }
      });
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error("error:", error);
    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Regarding your first question:**

> My question is, when the login happens and the credentials are stored, should I PUT a new action called something like CHAT_CONNECT which would kick off another saga to connect to Chatkit, or should I get the chat saga to listen to the LOGIN_SUCCESS being fired and act on that?

With the information provided its difficult to decide which approach is ideal because either will accomplish the same functionality.  The biggest difference I see between the two proposed approaches is the direction of dependency.  You have two different "modules" (features, packages, ...whatever you call your chunks of code that handle a single responsiblity), lets call them `log-in` and `connect-chat`.

If you dispatch an action `CHAT_CONNECT` from within the `log-in` saga, your `log-in` module will be dependent to the `connect-chat` module.  Presumably, the `connect-chat` action will live in the `connect-chat` module.

Alternatively, if your  `connect-chat` saga waits for `LOGIN_SUCCESS`, then your `connect-chat` module will be dependent on your `log-in` module.  Presumably, the `LOGIN_SUCCESS` will live in the `log-in` module.

There's nothing wrong with either approach.  Which is best depends on your applications needs and functionality.

If you might want to connect to chat any other time then after successfully logging in, then it might make sense to dispatch `CHAT_CONNECT` from within your `log-in` saga.  Because chat is no longer dependent on log in.  There are several scenarios where either approach will work better than the other, but it really depends on how the rest of your application is set up.

**Regarding your bonus questions:**

One approach to hooking external events in redux-saga is accomplished via `eventChannel`s.  Docs: https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#eventchannelsubscribe-buffer-matcher

There's a bit of boiler plate, but I found this approach makes testing easier and truly encapsulates external functionality.  Here's a quick example of how I might hook up an event channel to the code snippet you provided:

```
export const createOnMessageChannel = () =>
  eventChannel((emit) => {
    chatManager
      .connect()
        .then(currentUser => {
          currentUser.subscribeToRoom({
            roomId: currentUser.rooms[0].id,
            hooks: {
              onNewMessage: message => emit({ message }),
            }
          });
        })
        .catch(error => emit({ error }));

    return () => {
        // Code to unsubscribe, e.g. chatManager.disconnet() ? 
    };
  });

export function* onMessage({ message, error }) {
  if (error) {
    yield put(handleError(error));
    return;
  }

  yield put(handleMessage(message));
}

// this is what you pass to your root saga
export function* createOnMessageSaga() {

  // using call because this makes it easier to test
  const channel = yield call(createOnMessageChannel);
  if (!channel) return;

  yield takeEvery(channel, onMessage);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect. I hadn't thought about it in terms of dependencies but you're right, it doesn't make sense to have my chat module dependent on login to function properly. It seems more logical that part of the login process is to kick off the chat connection so I'll dispatch a new action from the login saga. Many thanks for making it clearer.

Comment: Awesome, glad it helped :)